# Java Number-Guessing Game Issue

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to build a Number Guessing Game in Java that is unlike the usual one where you guess the number and the program tells you whether it is high or low. I am trying to build one where the program guesses the number and you say whether it is high or low until the program finds the number you chose.

I am having an issue with the "if" statement where the number that the program guesses is too low.

The specific issue is here:

```
if (hilow.equals("l"))
        {
            middle = middle * 2;
            System.out.println(middle);
            numbGuesses++;
        }
```

The entire program so far is the following:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumbGuess
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int numbGuesses = 0;
        boolean win = false;
        int hi = 1000000;
        int low = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int middle = hi / 2;
        System.out.println(middle);


    while (win == false)
    {
        String hilow = input.nextLine();

        if (hilow.equals("h"))
        {
            middle = middle / 2;
            System.out.println(middle);
            numbGuesses++;
        }

        if (hilow.equals("l"))
        {
            middle = middle * 2;
            System.out.println(middle);
            numbGuesses++;
        }

        if (hilow.equals("y"))
        {
            win = true;
            System.out.println("It took: " + numbGuesses + " guesses");
        }
    }
}
}
```

The issue I am running into is a permanent loop whenever the number is too low:

[image]

I think I need to change what middle is operated by in order to get a working result.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is flawed. When the number is too low, you shouldn't just multiply by 2, and when it's too high, you shouldn't just divide by 2.

The new guess should be in the middle of the range. If your first guess is 500000, and the user says it's too low, the number is between 500000 and the max number (1000000), so the new guess should be `(1000000-500000)/2=750000`, not `500000*2`. If the first guess is too high, the number is between the min number (0) and 500000, so the next guess should be `(500000-0)/2=250000`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm new to this and this is my little pet project. Your response has been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with both the high and low `if` statements. You need to adjust your bounds each time a guess is made, for example if the guess was too high, the new `high` bound needs to be set to the guess. Similarly, if the guess was too low, then the new `low` bound needs to be set to the guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not a permanent loop. This program is doing exactly what you are asking:

It says 500000, you said for it to divide by 2 (=250000). Then, you said for it to multiply by 2 (=500000). And so far...

The problem is in your logic. You should proper establish the limits (`hi` and `low`) when the program receives an information. For instance, if the program guesses 500000, and you said it's too high, now your limits are between 1 and 499999 (=500000-1). If it's too low, now your limits are between 500001 (=500000+1) and 1000000 Every guess you recalculate the `middle` with your `hi` and `low` (`(hi+low)/2`).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you're using to change the computer's guess is not quite correct. What you want to be doing (and what it looks like you're trying to do) is a **binary search**.

In your example, 50000 is too high, 25000 is too low, so the next guess shouldn't double 25000, it should be in the middle of 50000 and 25000, or something like 37500.

In general, you should track the 'lowest guess that was too high' and the 'highest guess that was too low', and the next guess should be halfway between them.

Answer (score 0):

You should dynamically change **hi** and **low**, and not keep them static. Depending on the user's response, the program should change the value of **hi** or **low** and replace it with the current **middle** decremented or incremented respectively, and then set the new **middle** by averaging the new **hi** and **low**.

Here's what I tried and it seems to work:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumbGuess
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int numbGuesses = 0;
        boolean win = false;
        int hi = 1000000;
        int low = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int middle = hi / 2;
        System.out.println(middle);


    while (win == false)
    {
        String hilow = input.nextLine();

        if (hilow.equals("h"))
        {
            hi = middle - 1;
            middle = (low + hi) / 2;

            System.out.println(middle);
            numbGuesses++;
        }

        if (hilow.equals("l"))
        {
            low = middle + 1;
            middle = (low + hi) / 2;

            System.out.println(middle);
            numbGuesses++;
        }

        if (hilow.equals("y"))
        {
            win = true;
            System.out.println("It took: " + numbGuesses + " guesses");
        }
    }
}
}
```